# cordova-plugin-mfp does not support cordova-android-12

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, sdk, mfp

While creating cordova application on android platform with cordova-plugin-mfp version "8.0.2023050905", doesn't add plugin while running command cordova platform add android.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/it/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/ says only cordova 11 support available is there any timeline for cordova-android 12 compatibility.

I am using cordova version 12, cordova-android 12, node 18.16.0, npm 9.5.1

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlMEF.png)

Comment: Ask the authors...